# Need To Configure TFS Build With Custom Build Script

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-4.0

I use the below script to queue build in TFS 2010 build server. This TFSBuil.proj runs successfully if I use locally with command:  **`MSBUILD.exe TFSBuild.proj`**
and get my staging folder. *I am trying hard to get this to build in build server. Lastly   the build ran to success (in 8 secs !) but did nothing at the end*. Logs indicate all targets called with success but dont see the result. Any help is very much appreciated and I am ready to work hand in hand for this. Thank you.

Comment: Is your build generating a log file.  If so what's in there?

Comment: It sounds a lot like your @(Solutions) list is evaluating to empty on the build machine...  As @dylansmith indicates above, a log file would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess (until hopefully the log file can be retrieved).. have you tried to verify the work folder mappings using `tf workfold` from the command line? I would do that "locally" and then on the build machine. You can do this from your workstation with sufficient permissions, but going to the build machine might help you see unexpected differences - this happened to me more than once :-).
Also, perhaps the definition of `<SolutionRoot>..\</SolutionRoot>` isn't appropriate for the existing mapping, i.e. it's going one level higher than what's mapped.

Hope this helps,
Jonno

Comment: OK I was optimistic about the log file.. I can't say that added a lot for me.

It's another shot in the dark but have you compared the contents of the TFSBuild.proj files?

It's possible that a different file was chosen or that you have uncommitted changes there.

Are you able to log in to the build machine and run `msbuild TFSBuild.proj` like you did locally?